# Simple geometry problem regarding fitting square inside a circle

Tags: geometry

> Consider a square of side $a$. Fit the largest possible circle inside it and a largest possible square inside the circle. What is the side length of the square.

Above is how I picture the situation [image]

And so the side length of the innermost square equals $\sqrt{\frac{a^2}{4}+\frac{a^2}{4}}=\frac{a}{\sqrt{2}}$. Is this true. Need help!

Comment: The side length of the square is $a$, as it says in the first sentence! :)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is.

We have that the diameter of the circle is equal to the side length of the bigger square.

We also have that the diagonal of the square is equal to the diameter of the circle, which is the side length of the square.

We have that $s\sqrt{2}=a$, so $s=\displaystyle \frac{a}{\sqrt{2}}$, which is exactly what you said.

Good job!